# Geofencing feature - Open Street Maps with Open layers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, openlayers-3

Geofencing - I am beginner in OS MAPS.We are planning to develop user defined fence,when user click on points of his own choice on map then it should join with a line and finally coming to last point loop should be closed.

To achieve that we have used Vector layer to draw the polygon.Now after finishing the polygon.
a)How could we get the co-ordinates(lat,long) values of the drawn polygon.
b)Also how can I load from the database and draw the same fence with the saved co-ordinates.

Could anyone suggest some solutions for the above.

Comment: You gotta start! Begin with a simple [drawing example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/draw-features.html) and (perhaps, a jsfiddle) inform here about your progress - what you already did and what is missing.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker - Thanks for the reply.I drew a polygon(Triangle for eg.) with Geometry Type : 'Polygon' , then after finishing with the polygon I double click and finish.If I place a button 'Fetch' outside map then how could I fetch the latitude longitude co-ordinates of the drawn polygon.

Comment: Are you able to put this on a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jonatas Walker -  http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju5390/2dkdcu1o/ We created a button which is outside the map.In output I drew a polygon and after finishing the polygon , I want to get the co-ordinates of the drawn polygon when I click the FetchData button.Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer, actually, I think you should split the *b) part* to another question since it raises many questions out of `Openlayers` scope, like: `PHP`, Database. So *a) part*:

```
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
    var feature = evt.feature;
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();
    var coords = geom.getCoordinates();
    console.info(coords);
    if(geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon){
        coords[0].forEach(function(each){
            var formated = ol.coordinate.toStringXY(each, 2);
            //just to visualize
            element_coords.innerHTML += formated + '<br>';
        });
    }
});
```

[Your Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/zrrpgwyd/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Fiddle was quite useful.

Comment: Let me know what is missing.

Comment: I have also doubt how we can place some array of points on the map.Next suppose I want to draw a polygon how could I know whether the points are inside of the polygon or not.In short if we draw polygon , we fetch the boundaries ,how to identify the points are inside polygon or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first accept my answer and then create a new question.

Comment: @ Jonatas Walker - Sure we will create as new question.

Comment: To finish this question, you should accept my answer as correct, next to my answer there is a button to do this.

Comment: @ Jonatas Walker - As you requested we have posted the above as new question . Please refer this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375716/geofencing-feature-place-map-points-drawn-polygon-identify-point-within-po

Comment: No, you didn't get it. You start a question and should finish it. I refer to this one, not that one.

Comment: (a part) is already answered by you.I was experimenting regarding the saving of the values obtained after drawing the polygon.So question that came to mind is this - a) how can we place some array of points on the OS map? 2)Suppose we want to draw a polygon. How could we know whether the points are inside of the polygon or not.How could we identify whether the points are inside the polygon or not? For doing the (b) part these questions got cross connected to save polygon contains which all points inside. Hoping you got my question. Any help would be appreciated.