# Geofencing feature - Place Map points ,polygon ,Identify point within polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I have two queries regarding Polygon in Open Layers.

1)How can we place some array of points on the OS map?

2)Suppose we want to draw a polygon. How could we know whether the points are inside of the polygon or not. In short if we draw a polygon, we fetch the boundaries: How can we identify whether the points are inside the polygon or not?

Any help would be appreciated as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the OpenLayers community!

1) See this example to learn how to add point(s) to a map: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/icon.html. I strongly suggest you also read the "concepts" tutorial: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/doc/tutorials/concepts.html

2) A polygon object has the `intersectsExtent` method, which can be used to see if an extent intersects with an extent.  After you have drawn the polygon, you could loop in the array of points and collect each one which extent intersects with the polygon. See the documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/doc/tutorials/concepts.html

I would separate the points and polygons into 2 layers to keep them separate and more easily loop in the point features.

Comment: Can you help me to add along this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju5390/jrtw6q59/  regarding placing array of points on OS map and fetching/ alerting / console when we click an external button fetch whether these points are inside the polygon or not.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/jrtw6q59/1/  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in the end, but this should help you understand what's possible to do.

Comment: I don't find an changes in your latest fiddle from jsfiddle.net/Sanju5390/jrtw6q59 .Things are the same.

Comment: @ Alexandre Dubé Thanks .